# Call stored procedure containing collection of records using callproc in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I am having a stored procedure in sql :

```
PROCEDURE sp_add_object_tags(
pi_account_id               IN  user_files.account_id%TYPE,
pi_object_id                IN  object_metadata.object_id%TYPE,
pi_all_tags_identified      IN  VARCHAR2,
pi_object_tag_tbl           IN  object_tag_tbl,
po_error_code               OUT NUMBER,
po_error_message            OUT VARCHAR2 )
```

where object_tag_tbl is collection OF object_tag_rec

object_tag_rec is RECORD with below fields(elements):

```
tag_type            VARCHAR2(1),
tag_category        VARCHAR2(100),
tag_key             VARCHAR2(250),
tag_value           VARCHAR2(250),
created_by          VARCHAR2(50)
```

When I am calling the above stored procedure using callproc

```
object_tag_rec = collections.namedtuple('object_tag_rec',['tag_type','tag_category','tag_key', 'tag_value', 'created_by'])
rec_params1=object_tag_rec("S","person","person","1","abc")
params = [rec_params1]
cur_var = cur.callproc('tejfilusr.pg_object_tagging.sp_add_object_tags', [1234, 5678, 'N', params, po_error_code, po_error_message])
```

it gives me an error "element 0 value is unsupported".
Is there any way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not directly use `collections.namedtuple` as Oracle object type.

I tried the below on *Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0* with **`Cx-Oracle-7.0.0`**  and **Python 3.6.4** and it works for me.

**Create TYPE**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE object_tag_rec AS OBJECT (
     tag_type       VARCHAR2(1),
     tag_category   VARCHAR2(100),
     tag_key        VARCHAR2(250),
     tag_value      VARCHAR2(250),
     created_by     VARCHAR2(50)
);
/
```

**Create collection**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE object_tag_tbl is TABLE OF object_tag_rec;
/
```

**Create Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure  sp_add_object_tags(
pi_account_id               IN  INT,
pi_object_id                IN  INT,
pi_all_tags_identified      IN  VARCHAR2,
pi_object_tag_tbl           IN  object_tag_tbl,
po_error_code               OUT NUMBER,
po_error_message            OUT VARCHAR2 )
AS 
BEGIN

   po_error_code    := 0;
   po_error_message := 'NO ERRORS';
END;
/
```

**code**

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pwd@//localhost:1521/dbname')
cur = conn.cursor()

recordTypeObj = conn.gettype("HR.OBJECT_TAG_REC") #mind the cases
tableTypeObj  = conn.gettype("HR.OBJECT_TAG_TBL")
params = tableTypeObj.newobject()

rec = recordTypeObj.newobject()
(rec.TAG_TYPE,rec.TAG_CATEGORY,rec.TAG_KEY,rec.TAG_VALUE,rec.CREATED_BY) = ("S","person","person","1","abc")  
#mind the cases for attributes.

po_error_code    = cur.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
po_error_message = cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)

params.append(rec)
cur.callproc('dbms_output.enable')
cur.callproc('hr.sp_add_object_tags', [1234, 5678, 'N', params, po_error_code, po_error_message])

print (po_error_code.getvalue(),po_error_message.getvalue())
```

**Execution**

```
$python pass_obj.py
0.0 NO ERRORS
```