# Call Oracle procedure from python and assign out varible to python lisr

Tags: python, oracle, plsql

I need to transfer the data to sftp server from the app server which call the procedure of DB server.

In DB, I have the following procedure.

```sql
create or replace type txn_data is table of varchar2(128);
    
create or replace procedure atm_txn_extract(
  txn_date in date, txn_data_d out txn_data
) 
is
begin
    select card_num||'|'||acc_no||'|'||txn_date||'|'||txn_amt||'|'||txn_time
    bulk collect into txn_data_d
    from atm_txn_data
    where txn_date=txn_date
end;
```

I want to call this procedure from a Python program and assign the Oracle out varible `txn_data_d` (collection-nested table) to a Python list variable. So that I can loop over the list and write into file and will be transferred to SFTP server.

Could you help me out how to assign oracle out variable to python list variable.

Comment: Probably a (simplified) duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53375917/1509264

Comment: Why are you using a collection containing a delimited string rather than just using a `SELECT` statement and getting the individual columns and then parsing the result set in Python? This seems like an excessively complicated solution to what should be a simple problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] containing: **YOUR** python code; the errors/issues with **YOUR** python code; the expected output.

Comment: Look at all the [cx_Oracle examples](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples) and read the [cx_Oracle documentation](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).